# Blocking all of tumblr from hosts file

Tags: web, hosts-file

I am trying to block tumblr, and all it's pages, using my hosts file. Usually I would just add an entry like

```
127.0.0.1 tumblr.com
```

to my file, but tumblr has websites in the format " sitename.tumblr.com"

I have tried

```
127.0.0.1 *.tumblr.com
127.0.0.1 http://*.tumbr.com
```

And neither work either. Does anyone know how to block tumblr without installing bulky software?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't use wildcards in the hosts file.

Answer (score 2):

You can block `static.tumblr.com` and `78.media.tumblr.com` and render the site basically unusable.

Answer (score 1):

I was searching and trying to block this shitty website and finally found the solution. There is nothing you can do with hosts file, except blocking the regular form of www addresses. Personally, I recommend to use Avast blocking sites tool. It works great and blocks all the tumblr subdomains. You have to add

```
http://*.tumblr.com*
```

in your "Blocked URL address list" and enable it.